# Permession denied error while installing pyldavis in conda env [Errorno 13]

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to install pyldavis in a conda env using the command: `conda install -c conda-forge pyldavis`
 but I get the following errors:

`ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-hfa6e2cd_0'`

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\<Path>\Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll'`

Comment: Try run it as administrator.

Comment: Thx for the reply. You mean to run the terminal as an admin or is there something I should add to the command? Also don't you think that the problem is in installing ``` openssl```

Comment: You should try to run the terminal (cmd) as administrator. If you are using MacOS or Linux, you can try: `sudo conda install -c conda-forge pyldavis`, but if you work in windows, run cmd as administrator and run the following command:` conda install -c conda-forge pyldavis`.

Comment: Is this solved? I am having the same problem but installing a different package. The error is relate to conda update actually. ```[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda-4.8.5-py3.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO' -> '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda-4.8.5-py3.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO.c~'```